# How to simplify this matrix equation?

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-equations, jacobian

I am working through a proof and have got stuck at a certain point.  Where I have reached is the following:
$$
q(\mathbf{x}) = \frac{|\mathbf{\Sigma}|^2}{(\mathbf{x}-\mathbf{x}_0)'\mathbf{\Sigma}'\mathbf{\Sigma}(\mathbf{x}-\mathbf{x}_0)+|\mathbf{\Sigma}|^2}
$$
in which $\mathbf{x}$, $\mathbf{x}_0$ are $m \times 1$ vectors, $\mathbf{\Sigma}$ is $m \times m$ matrix and $|\mathbf{\Sigma}|$ is the determinant of $\mathbf{\Sigma}$, which is in fact the Jacobian matrix of a system of $m$ functions $\mathbf{f}(\mathbf{x}) = [f_i(\mathbf{x}),...,f_m(\mathbf{x})]'$, $f_i(\mathbf{x}):\mathbb{R}^m \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$.

Related work strongly suggests that the above reduces to
$$
q(\mathbf{x}) = \frac{1}{(\mathbf{x}-\mathbf{x}_0)'(\mathbf{x}-\mathbf{x}_0) + 1}.
$$
Can anyone provide the remaining step(s)?  Or alternatively advise if this is not possible.

EDIT: On reflection, it would be adequate to demonstrate (if it is possible to do so) that
$$
||q(\mathbf{x})||_2 = \frac{1}{(\mathbf{x}-\mathbf{x}_0)'(\mathbf{x}-\mathbf{x}_0) + 1}.
$$.

Comment: Your reduction cannot possibly be true, because the various terms appearing here don't scale the same way with scaling $\Sigma$. The determinant terms scale much faster than the $\Sigma' \Sigma$ term.

Comment: Qiaochu Yuan is absolutely right. You could have easily answered this question yourself by substituting some simple matrix like $Σ=λ$ or simply evaluating both quantities numerically for some examples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best simplification i can see is rewriting the equation as

$$ q(x) = \frac{1}{1+\big\|\frac{Σ}{|Σ|}(x-x_0)\big\|_2^2} $$

This is generally equal to $\frac{1}{1+\|x-x_0\|_2^2}$ if and only if $Σ$ is orthogonal. Apart from that you can write it as a geometric series or derivative of arctan, if $|\det(Σ)|>ρ(Σ)$.

$$ q(x) 
= \frac{1}{1+\big\|\frac{Σ}{|Σ|}(x-x_0)\big\|_2^2} 
= \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} (-1)^k \Big\|\frac{Σ}{|Σ|}(x-x_0)\Big\|_2^{2k}
= \frac{\arctan(\big\|\frac{Σ}{|Σ|}(x-x_0)\big\|)}{\big\|\frac{Σ}{|Σ|}(x-x_0)\big\|} 
$$

Comment: Having considered your answer I have reflected on the proof I would like to achieve (if it is possible to do so) and added it to the end of the question.  Is this revised objective more achievable?  Since $\Sigma$ is a Jacobian matrix, I don't think it can be guaranteed to be orthogonal.

Comment: @RickyBoy your $q(x)$ is by definition already a scalar, so $‖q(x)‖_2$ is just the same as the absolute value of $q(x)$. Again, you can **easily** perform a sanity check yourself by just plugging in some random values.

Comment: Sure, I have done so and it indeed confirms the objective cannot be fulfilled in its current form so I need to go back a step or two because all evidence suggests the result is correct but clearly not attainable from the form of $q(x)$ I had reached so far.  Your engagement has been valuable, thank you.